# Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a countdown timer that stops when it has gone down to 0 seconds. Every thing works except that it should stop at o seconds.

please answer if you know why the error occurred or how to solve it.

```
func stopAt() {
    if countLabel.text = "0" {
        if timerRunning == true {                
            timer.invalidate()
            timerRunning = false                    
        }       
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`=` is assignment, `==` is comparison. You want to *compare* `countLabel.text` with `"0"`, not *assign* `"0"` to `countLabel.text`.

```
func stopAt() {
   if countLabel.text == "0" {
       if timerRunning {
           timer.invalidate()
           timerRunning = false
       }   
   }
}
```

Also, you never need to compare with `true` or `false` explicitely.